# How to get caret position for a contenteditable 'div' in Angular 2?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have the following code:

```
<div #test (click)="onClick(test)" contenteditable="true">
            This text can be edited by the user.
</div>

@ViewChild('test') el:ElementRef;

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

onClick(event) {
  console.log(this.el.nativeElement); 
  let cursor = this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart; //gives undefined
}
```

How do I get the cursor position for the 'div' element when user clicks on the text?

Answer (score 0):

`selectionStart` is property of HTMLInputElement.

```
<div #test (click)="onClick(test)" contenteditable="true">
            This text can be edited by the user.
</div>

to 

<input  #test (click)="onClick(test)"  
  value='This text can be edited by the user.' />
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks, but I really need to use <div> instead of <input>. I can get the range using 'window.getSelection()', but I read somewhere it's unsafe to manipulate DOM like this in Angular 2.

Comment: @swapp1990, this is not exactly manipulating - you're not changing anything in the DOM, just reading a property. Though discouraged, this is your only option if you really need to measure something in the DOM.

Comment: This is not the answer of this question, the question is asking how to get caret of contenteditable, not input !